# How to insert data and override if existing from one database to another? Using SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I want to copy the data of specific table from other database(DB2) to my current database(DB1) and override the existing data of my current database(DB1) with the same ID from other database(DB2) using SQL Server 2016.

I want to specifically merge the `table` of `DB1` to `DB2` as there's also table that I don't want to get modified.

```
eg. 
  I have table Config of DB1:
     +--------+----------+
     |   ID   |  Status  |
     +--------+----------+
     |   1    |  Active  |
     +--------+----------+
     |   2    | Inactive |
     +--------+----------+
     |   3    |  Active  |
     +--------+----------+


  Here I have my DB2 with table Config
     +--------+----------+
     |   ID   |  Status  |
     +--------+----------+
     |   1    |  Active  |
     +--------+----------+
     |   2    |  Active  |
     +--------+----------+
     |   3    |  Active  |
     +--------+----------+
     |   4    | Inactive |
     +--------+----------+


 Output should be after the insertion of table Config data from DB2 to DB1:
         +--------+----------+
         |   ID   |  Status  |
         +--------+----------+
         |   1    |  Active  |
         +--------+----------+
         |   2    |  Active  |
         +--------+----------+
         |   3    |  Active  |
         +--------+----------+
         |   4    | Inactive |
         +--------+----------+
```

Comment: Try using merge if you would like to with update and insert option.

Comment: Is the merge will merge the whole DB1 to DB2? or there's option that I can select table that I want to be merge only?

Comment: Yes you can select the table using that.

Comment: How can I do that? Is that application? or Query? Do you have link of that?

Comment: can you clarify what do you need to merge ? is it `DATABASE` or `TABLE` ? you uses both term in your question

Comment: I want to merge specific table of two databases.

Comment: is the `database` reside on the same server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assumed your db1 as your target table and db2 as your source, and you can use in this way.

```
Creating table 

select 1 as ID, 'Active' as [status]   into #db1 
union all  
select 2 as ID, 'InActive' as [status]  
union all 
select 3 as ID, 'Active' as [status]  


 select 1 as ID, 'Active' as [status]   into #db2
 union all  
 select 2 as ID, 'Active' as [status]  
 union all 
 select 3 as ID, 'Active' as [status]  
 union all 
 select 4 as ID, 'InActive' as [status]
```

Logic: if the db1 ID and db2 ID matches and if the same ID has active in DB2 and inactive in db1, it will update db1 with active status. When there is no match in ID suppose 4 which exists only in db2 and not in db1, it will insert.

```
merge #db1 as t 
using #db2 as s on t.ID = s.ID 
when matched  and t.[status] = 'InActive' and s.[status] = 'Active' 
then 
update 
set t.[status] = s.[status] 
when not matched   then 
insert values(s.ID, s.[status]); 

select * from #db1
```

Output:

```
ID  status
1   Active
2   Active 
3   Active
4   InActive
```

Comment: Noted. This just happened that we need to merge the production settings and the changes settings on local without modifying the other table.